# async.each won't run the callback

Tags: node.js

I am trying to call some URLs asynchronously and collect the results. I've done it with "Promises". Now I'm trying to wrap my head around async.js.

Here is a code snipped:

```
var request = require("request"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio");
    // base_url = "http://de.indeed.com/Jobs?q=";  // after equal sign for instance:   sinatra&l=
var async = require('async');

/* search syntax:
   - http://de.indeed.com/Jobs?q=node&l=berlin&radius=100
*/

var search_words = ["django", "python", "flask",
                    "rails", "ruby",
                    "node", "javascript", "angularjs", "react", "express", "meteor",
                    "java", "grails", "groovy",
                    "php", "symfony", "laravel" ];


var base_url = "http://de.indeed.com/Jobs?q=";
var stats = [];


async.each(search_words, function(keyword)  {
    var url = base_url + keyword + "&l=";
    request( base_url + keyword + "&l=", function(err, resp, body) {
        if (err) throw err;
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        num_str = $("#searchCount")[0].children[0].data.split(" ").reverse()[0];
        num_str = num_str.replace(/\./, "");
        num_str = num_str.replace(/,/, "");

        stats.push( [keyword, num_str] );
    });
}, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(stats);
});
```

According to [this](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) I can pass a callback function as last argument to async.each that will be triggered once the array has been processed.

In my case the callback never gets triggered it seems.

Btw: Trevor Burnham mentions in his book "Async Javascript" the function asyn.forEach It seems this has been removed from async.js?

---

@robertklep gave me a tip to add a callback to the iteratee function. // This is the working version:

```
var request = require("request"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio");
    // base_url = "http://de.indeed.com/Jobs?q=";  // after equal sign for instance:   sinatra&l=
var async = require('async');

/* search syntax:
   - http://de.indeed.com/Jobs?q=node&l=berlin&radius=100
*/

var search_words = ["django", "python", "flask",
                    "rails", "ruby",
                    "node", "javascript", "angularjs", "react", "express", "meteor",
                    "java", "grails", "groovy",
                    "php", "symfony", "laravel" ];


var base_url = "http://de.indeed.com/Jobs?q=";
var stats = [];

async.each(search_words, function(keyword, callback)  {
    var url = base_url + keyword + "&l=";
    request( url, function(err, resp, body) {
        if (err) {
            callback("ERROR in request");
        } else {
            $ = cheerio.load(body);
            num_str = $("#searchCount")[0].children[0].data.split(" ").reverse()[0];
            num_str = num_str.replace(/\./, "");
            num_str = num_str.replace(/,/, "");
            num = parseInt(num_str);

            stats.push( [keyword, num] );
            callback();
        }
    });
}, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        stats_sorted = stats.sort( function(a, b) {
            return b[1] - a[1];
        });
        console.log(stats_sorted);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the part where the iteratee gets *two* arguments: the item *and* a callback. This callback needs to be called when the iteratee has completed (or when an error has occurred):

```
async.each(search_words, function(keyword, callback)  {
  var url = base_url + keyword + "&l=";
  request( base_url + keyword + "&l=", function(err, resp, body) {
      if (err) return callback(err);

      $ = cheerio.load(body);
      num_str = $("#searchCount")[0].children[0].data.split(" ").reverse()[0];
      num_str = num_str.replace(/\./, "");
      num_str = num_str.replace(/,/, "");

      stats.push( [keyword, num_str] );

      return callback();
  });
}, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(stats);
});
```

Given that you are mapping each of `search_words` to a value, you should consider using [`async.map()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#mapcoll-iteratee-callback) instead. That way, you won't need the separate `stats` array.

`.each()` and `.forEach()` used to be synonyms, but in recent versions, `.forEach()` has been removed.

Comment: You are right about the callback part.  

But instead of returning a callback `return callback();` wouldn't I have to just do `callback();` ? Isn't this used in Continuation Passing Style (CPS): instead of returning from a function you'd give control to another function.

Comment: Also, if I do a `console.log( [keyword, num_str]);` prior to `stats.push( [keyword, num_str])` I get the right data. Why is `stats.push( [keyword, num_str] );` not appending to the stats array? Or is it?

Comment: @Ugur sorry, `return callback()` may look confusing, as you are right in that calling `callback()` without the `return` is sufficient (only that last call, though; the `callback(err)` should be either prefixed with `return` or it should be followed by it). However, I always prefix calling callbacks with a `return`, not so much because I actually want to return _a value_, but calling the callback signals the end of the current function and by returning from it, you can be sure that the rest of the code won't run. As for `stats.push(...)`: that should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure you need to passback the result in the callback once you return a response from request

```
request( base_url + keyword + "&l=", function(err, resp, body) {
        if (err) throw err;
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        num_str = $("#searchCount")[0].children[0].data.split(" ").reverse()[0];
        num_str = num_str.replace(/\./, "");
        num_str = num_str.replace(/,/, "");

        stats.push( [keyword, num_str] );
    });
```